# What does linear equivalence geometrically mean for varieties?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, motivation

Suppose we have a sufficiently nice scheme or say we are working with an abstract nonsingular variety $X$ over an algebraically close field. In this setting, one can study (Weil) divisors. It is then said that two divisors $D,D'\in\operatorname{Div}(X)$ (i.e. formal finite linear combinations of prime divisors) are *linearly equivalent*  $D\sim D'$ if $\operatorname{div}(f)=D-D'$ for some function $f$ inside the function field $K(X)$.

I have pondered this choice of terminology for some time. Even in the case of curves, I do not precisely see why we call them linearly equivalent instead of anything else?

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated. I have searched the internet and this site for potential answers and have not found a satisfactory answer.

Comment: There is a family of divisors parametrized by $ \mathbb{P}^1 $, such that the fiber over $ 0 $ is $ D $ and that over $ \infty $ is $ D' $. Atleast that's what I see it as, geometrically, linear comes from $ \mathbb{P}^1 $.

Comment: I don't know if this is the original reason, but imagine that $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ is a projective variety. Then for any hyperplane $H$, we have a divisor $D_H=X \cap H$. These divisors are all equivalent, which is clear by taking a function $f$ with zeros in one hypeplane and poles in the other one.

Comment: I think both of these comments are acceptable answers. A reference to this motivation or a more detailed answer is completely acceptable to me. I'll accept either if they are posted.